# jQuery sort function on dynamic data attribute

Tags: jquery, sorting, attributes

I'm using the sort function to re-order my divs numerically (1-2-3)

```
function sortByShop_reOrder() {
   $('#store_list .store_item').sort(function(a, b) {
      return $(a).data('order') - $(b).data('order');
   }).appendTo('#store_list');
 }


<div id="store_list">
   <div class="store_item store_item_11" data-order="1">1</div>
   <div class="store_item store_item_21" data-order="2">2</div>
   <div class="store_item store_item_22" data-order="3">3</div>
</div>
```

I have a ajax call that runs every 15 seconds:

```
 $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "someURL",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: "data=random",
        success:function(data) {
          var array = data;
              $.each(array, function (i) {
                  var store_order = array[i]['store_order'];
                  var store_id = array[i]['store_id'];
                  $('.store_item_'+store_id).attr('data-order', store_order);
              });
          sortByShop_reOrder()
        }
})
```

ARRAY (store_ids differ to my code below):
[image]

this dynamically updates the data-order attribute value:

```
<div id="store_list">
   <div class="store_item store_item_11" data-order="1">1</div>
   <div class="store_item store_item_22" data-order="3">3</div>
   <div class="store_item store_item_21" data-order="2">2</div>
</div>
```

Now when I rerun the sortByShop_reOrder() it does not re-order my divs (1-2-3) it just remains the same (1-3-2).

Any ideas? Is the function not seeing the updated data-order value?

Comment: wupps spelling mistake..anywho the issue still remains

Comment: Since your `sortByShop_reOrder` **works pretty fine**, why not show the  way you're calling it - after your supposedly dynamic attributes change?

Comment: Unable to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/291kn8s5/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've updated my question

Comment: Try using `$('.store_item_' + store_id).data('order', store_order);`. This is because there can be inconsistencies when mixing between accessing data attributes using `attr()` and `data()`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Apologies ive added those already - completely forgot to add to my question - Issue still remains tho

Comment: See your AJAX code, you first set a var named `store_order` but you use it like `store_id` - which is clearly incorrect :)

Comment: OK, now can you `console.log(store_id)` somewhere to be 100% sure you're getting the right IDs?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Apologies again - i've added that VAR  - issue remains - lordy i'm terrible at providing all the details correctly apologies

Comment: To recap... the way you sort your items is perfectly fine. You just need to 100% ensure your data has the right IDs and that such classes really exist `.store_item_ID`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i'm getting all the IDs and they are updating the data-id attribute for the corresponding store_ids

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i've uploaded a screenshot - store_ids are different to the ones i have in the question but you get the idea of what data it returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`.data()` Method](https://api.jquery.com/data/) since you sort by `.data()`:

```
$.each(dataArr, function(i, obj) {
  $('.store_item_' + obj.store_id).data('order', obj.store_order); // Update data
});
sortByShop_reOrder(); // sort by data
```

Example:

```js
function sortByShop_reOrder() {
  $('#store_list .store_item').sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data('order') - $(b).data('order');
  }).appendTo('#store_list');
}

function demoAJAX(dataArr) {
  $.each(dataArr, function(i, obj) {
    $('.store_item_' + obj.store_id).data('order', obj.store_order);
  });
  sortByShop_reOrder()
}

sortByShop_reOrder(); // do immediately and...
setTimeout(function(){ // after 4 sec
  demoAJAX([
    {"store_order":"1", "store_id":"11"},
    {"store_order":"2", "store_id":"21"},
    {"store_order":"3", "store_id":"22"}
  ])
}, 4000);
```

```html
<div id="store_list">
  <div class="store_item store_item_11" data-order="2">2</div>
  <div class="store_item store_item_21" data-order="3">3</div>
  <div class="store_item store_item_22" data-order="1">1</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That did the trick! many many! thanks for being so patient! and taking the time to help  i'm sending you a virtual beer!